# Efficency data storage in Android

Tags: android, database, caching, storage

I need to store localisated data from the web, which comes in a `JSON` string. So far I have a `DataAdapter` which expects data in a `JSONObject` and collectes the data for visualisation. But now I have no caching at all.

I want to store the data from the last call including a `Etag` for observing changes. So I want to show at first the cached data and look on the web if there are some changes and show them as far they are aviable. I see there three options:

- Plain storage of the whole JSON in a file
- Storage of the data in a SQLite database
- Using a [CouchDB for Android](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase)

I'm not sure which way is most efficency... I want also to store/cache images. By the way I also want that the data are encrypted so far the *storage system* must not write any data directly on the flash memory, when seconds later comes another bound of data. And also I want to save the battery.

**Which is the most energy efficency way to store data?

Which is the fastes way to store data?**

Comment: There is a bunch of information about how to make the most efficient use of caching and the network when making an app on the AT&T developer site http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042

Comment: This is a really good ressource, but I know most stuff from that page... If you could post a link about caching on the client side I would be happy to accept such a link as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to extends a `LruCache` where I override the `sizeOf` function to get the real size.

For `Drawable`s I use this code:

```
if(rawdata  instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)rawdata).getBitmap();
    mem += bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For small web-service requests you can use [ResponseCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ResponseCache.html). When dealing with larger objects you might want to create your own cache.

You could also:

- Serialize the data and save it to a local file
- For basic data you could save it in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if it is meant to be stored for a longer period
- Use sqlite if you have a large amount of data and you need to perform relational operations on it.

For image caching, see:

[Android image caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-caching)

[Android: Image cache strategy and memory cache size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085366/android-image-cache-stategy-and-memory-cache-size?rq=1)

Comment: Caching data into the browser cache looks like an interessting idea but I cannot use the `URL` class because it does not support the ntlm auth scheme. However I want to encrypt the stored data and none of your links seems to provide a encryption support. I saw in one refered question the `SoftReference` class looks very helpful. thx